# How to save a text file to a .mat file?

Tags: python-2.7, matlab, text-files, mat-file

How do I save a '*.txt' file as a '*.mat' file, using either MATLAB or Python?
I tried using textscan() (in MATLAB), and scipy.io.savemat() (in Python). Both didn't help.

My text file is of the format: value1,value2,value3,valu4 (each row) and has over 1000 rows.

Appreciate any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `textscan` to read the file and `save` to save the variables into a .mat file

```
fid = fopen('yourTextFile.txt');
C = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f');
fclose(fid);
% maybe change the cells from `C` to a single matrix
M = cell2mat(C);
save('myMatFile.mat','M');
```

This works because your file seems to have a fixed format. 
Have a look at [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)

Comment: When I run this, I get the following error:Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

      Error in cell2mat (line 75)
            m{n} = cat(2,c{n,:});

Comment: Can you please give more information about the content of your file and the dimension of each cell in `C`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using csvread() as follows:

```
file = csvread('yourTextFile.txt');
save('myMatFile.mat','file');
```

Answer (score -3):

if what you need is to change file format:
`mv example.mat example.txt`